# How to use a template for configuration file in Puppet

Tags: linux, templates, configuration, puppet

I am new to Puppet and I am writing a module to setup configuration files. The problem is when  multiple clients will be using my module they will have to edit it according to their system. I have heard that templates are way to solve this problem. But I am not able to get it how to use a template for setting up configuration file.

If anyone of you can give me a simple to follow example using templates to configure files would be really helpful. For example how can i setup Apache sites-available default configuration file using template, or give any other example you feel will help a new puppet user. BTW I am on Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The PuppetLabs docs on [Using templates](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_template.html) has an example of an Apache configuration for a Trac site. This should be enough to get you started.

Per OP's request, here's a simple example. I'm using NTP rather than the Apache default config since that's a fairly large and complex file. NTP is much simpler.

Directory looks like this:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/ntp/manifests
                       /templates
```

Partial contents `/etc/puppet/modules/ntp/manifests/init.pp` (just the portion defining the template):

```
$ntp_server_suffix = ".ubuntu.pool.ntp.org"

file { '/etc/ntp.conf':
    content => template('ntp/ntp.conf.erb'),
    owner   => root,
    group   => root,
    mode    => 644,
}
```

Contents of `/etc/puppet/modules/ntp/templates/ntp.conf.erb`:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
<% [1,2].each do |n| -%>
server <%=n-%><%=@ntp_server_suffix%>
<% end -%>

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
```

When run with puppet this will result in an `/etc/ntp.conf` that looks like:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
```

This demonstrates a few different concepts:

1. Variables defined in the puppet manifest (such as `$ntp_server_suffix` can be accessed as instance variables (`@ntp_server_suffix`) in the template
2. Loops and other ruby code can be used in erb templates
3. Code between `<%` and `%>` is executed by ruby
4. Code between `<%=` and `%>` is executed and output by ruby
5. Code between `<%=` and `-%>` is executed and output by ruby and the trailing newline character is suppressed.

Hope this helps you understand templates.

Comment: thanks ben..:)... I looked on to the documentation its a little complex. Is there a small example you can suggest? Thanks

Comment: awesome ben.. thanks alot.. that really gave me a good understanding of how templates work. I had to install ntp and then I compared it with how you are modifying it in the puppet code :)...thanks again..

Comment: Content line should be content => template('ntp/ntp.conf.erb')